# What is the meaning of $\delta(ax + by - t)$

Tags: dirac-delta

How one deals with 2D delta function $\delta(x+y)$?

Is $\delta (x+y)$ same as $\delta(x,y)=\delta(x) \delta(y)$ ?

It appears in radon transforms. Below is special case that I am interested in.
$$\int\int \delta (ax+by-t) f(x)g(y) dx dy $$

Comment: Please provide an expression where the thing appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is simply a 1-D Dirac impulse being zero for non-zero argument, and satisfying

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta(x+y)dx=f(-y)$$

Comment: Thanks, but how one would solve $$\int\int \delta (x+y) f(x)g(y) dx dy $$

Comment: @Anonymous: You would get $$\int f(-y)g(y)dy$$